# Chrome duplicate console entries

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to create a YouTube extension and in the console I get duplicate entries.
[image]

This makes debugging it more difficult as I have to constantly find in which entry all the console messages are going. I was wondering if there is any way to remove the entry when the extension is disabled or updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [orphaned content script contexts](/a/57471345) created when reloading the extension and using executeScript to inject a new content script. Due to a [bug in Chrome](https://crbug.com/1314400) simply reloading the tab won't help.

The only way to remove them:

1. terminate the tab in Chrome's built-in Task Manager,
2. then reload the tab.

And a trick to simplify selecting the correct context:

1. set a breakpoint in your content script, don't close devtools;
2. reload the extension or perform any action for which your new content script has a listener where you added the breakpoint;
3. now devtools should be paused on the breakpoint, just click the context selector and you'll see which one is current - it will be highlighted.